# Build a bar chart with a small step in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a dataset of about 100 time measurements, from 4.5 to 5.5 seconds. I need to build a chart with a bar for every 0.01 of a second (a bar for 4.5, a bar for 4.51, a bar for 4.52, etc. to 5.5), with the height of the bar representing the number of times that value has been recorded. Some of the values have not been recorded, so there should be a gap in the chart in those places instead of a bar.

The code for plotting now is

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(4.50, 5.50, step=0.01))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 5, step=1))
plt.xlim(4.50,5.50)
plt.ylim(0,5)
plt.bar(t, m)
plt.show()
```

It does not do what I want at all, instead showing this [the height of the bars is incorrect, and it does not represent the values not recorded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/se7NR.png)

Comment: sounds like you should create a histogram with 0.01-width bins

Comment: You didn't set a width for the bars. By default, the bars are `0.8` wide, making them overlap a lot.  You might try something like `plt.bar(t, m, width=0.01, facecolor='skyblue', edgecolor='black')`.

Comment: Now the diagram itself looks alright, thanks! But the marks on the x axis are still overlapping and therefore unreadable, can I fix that as well?